# Creating a C++ FTP Server

Tags: c++, sockets, ftp

I need to transfer some files over FTP to a mobile device.  I chose against using bare sockets because I wanted the ease of access that an FTP server provides. I want to create my own FTP Server through C++.  I tried [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cftpserver/) class, but was getting some errors trying to get it to work.  Does anyone know of a class, example, or library to use when building a C++ FTP Server?

Comment: A library to use? Sockets, duh :) Either you take an implementation of the FTP protocol or you implement the protocol yourself on top of sockets

Comment: Well, I want a wrapper on top of sockets, so I don't have to make my own :)

Comment: What is your target mobile OS?

Comment: Android, I would be using the apache commons FTP protocol

Comment: @crocboy what abstractions would you want this wrapper to provide? Most abstractions over TCP sockets are network protocols, and you're about to implement one of them

Comment: Well, I just want an easy-to-use class, like the one I linked in the above question.  Nothing fancy, just a basic server with the ability to connect one or two clients.  No passwords, usernames, or anything.

Comment: You may be approaching this backwards. You could instead use the Apache Commmons `FTPClient` (or similar, specific to Android) to pull files from a pre-existing FTP server to the device. Also afaik C++ development on Android is a rats' nest.

Comment: No, I'll be using the C++ on a desktop to create a server, and then using the Android device to access that server.

Comment: I see.  There are free FTP servers out there, but if you want to write your own, that's fine.

Comment: I need to write my own as part of an existing program that's already built, and I need to be able to control it at will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`boost::asio`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). Boost is a very well-know set of libraries for C++, and `asio` is the part implementing the support for networking.

[Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) you can see a list of examples, ranging from simple example to an HTTP server. Unluckily there is no example creating an FTP server, but the examples in the previous link will point you in the right direction.

Of course, if you do not need to build your own FTP server, then you can look for some projects out there that fully implement an FTP server.

Comment: I got it to work, using the open() and read() functions from 'fstream'.  I can convert to an XML on the Android side and it works nicely